# Issue with recalling information

Tags: javascript

I am new at Java Script and I was just trying to practice what I have learnt.

I tried to create a text field then access and recall the information.

```
<body>

<form>
  Name of the book You have read: <input id="books" type="text" name="ewq" value="qwe">
  <input  type="submit" name="ui" value="submit" onClick="bookse()">
</form>

<p id="qwe">name:</p>

<script type="text/javascript">
function bookse() {
  var nameofbook = document.getElementById('books').value;
  document.getElementsById('qwe').innerHTML = nameofbook;
}
</script>
</body>
```

And then I tried with Local Storage

```
<form id="book">
  Name of the book You have read: <input id="books" type="text" name="" value="">
</form>

<p>name:</p>

<script type="text/javascript">
var x = document.getElementById('books');
if (localStorage.books) {
  localStorage.books = x;
  document.getElementsByTagName('p').innerHTML = x;
}
</script>
```

And none of them worked. What are my mistakes

Comment: The first: you're submitting the form which is going to cause a redirect (kind of like clicking on a link). The second: notice how it says "getElement**s**ByTagName"? It's a collection of elements, not just one. I'd highly suggest getting familiar [with your console.](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/185/getting-started-with-javascript/714/using-console-log) It will tell you what's wrong with your code.

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementsById('qwe').innerHTML = nameofbook;
```

There is no function `document.getElementsById()`, this should be `getElementById`:

```
document.getElementById('qwe').innerHTML = nameofbook;
```

---

The example using local storage seems rather pointless to me, as you never read the storage contents, aside from other issues.